# Angular2 -- @ViewChild from TypeScript base abstract class

Tags: angular, angular-routing, viewchild

I was looking @ [this SO Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286936/can-the-viewchildren-decorator-in-angular2-work-with-interfaces), and wondering if it was possible to have a base `abstract class` instead?  Rather than an `interface`, is it possible to have differing implementations of a base class in child components that are accessible to the parent component via the `@ViewChild` decorator in **Angular2**?

Ideally, I would like to have a means for child components that are instantiated via a parent `Router` to be capable of invoking the parent router -- does that make sense?  I want the child to be able to call `parentRouter.navigate(["SomeOtherRoute", { args: 'blah' }]);`.

My initial approach was to have the child components implement a base class that the parent component would get a reference to via the `@ViewChild` decorator. The parent would `subscribe` to the action of the child attempting to invoke a navigation event, and its handler would invoke the `router.navigate` (since it has the router at the parent level).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `@ViewChildren()` or any of the similar decorators to query for subclasses of components.

Only names of template variables and concrete component and directive types (the types that are actually instantiated as component in your view) are supported.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to then implement the service approach defined here, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service.

Comment: That's usually the preferred way.

Answer (score 28):

It is actually quite simple. For instance, if you have a class EmployeeComponent that extends PersonComponent which is an abstract class.

You can make it approachable by adding this in the EmployeeComponent:

`providers: [ {provide: PersonComponent, useExisting: EmployeeComponent }]`

And use ViewChildren() or ContentChildren() in your container component like this:

`@ViewChildren(PersonComponent) public persons: QueryList<PersonComponent>;`

Comment: This should be the correct answer, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is possible, and I find it can be cleaner in some cases, although for your use case I think a service is preferrable. See my answer to the original question about interfaces. I maybe should have posted it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151492/4293638